# Start external application maximized over taskbar (fullscreen)

Tags: c#, c++, fullscreen, taskbar

How can i start external application in "fullscreen" mode (without borders and over taskbar)? And is it possible to do this using only .Net Framework library? Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you developing in C# or C++?

Comment: Both. Will choose depends on resolving of my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Raymond Chen suggests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx), the best way to create a fullscreen window that covers up the taskbar is simply by creating a fullscreen window without a border.

Since your question is tagged C++, I'll assume you can translate this code into its .NET equivalent:

```
HWND CreateFullscreenWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
    HMONITOR hmon = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    MONITORINFO mi = { sizeof(mi) };

    if (!GetMonitorInfo(hmon, &mi)) return NULL;

    return CreateWindow(TEXT("static"),
                        TEXT("something interesting might go here"),
                        WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
                        mi.rcMonitor.left,
                        mi.rcMonitor.top,
                        mi.rcMonitor.right - mi.rcMonitor.left,
                        mi.rcMonitor.bottom - mi.rcMonitor.top,
                        hwnd, NULL, g_hinst, 0);
}
```

Comment: I need to start external app, not window of my own.

Comment: @archer: You're not going to be able to change the border style of an external app. But you *can* make it fill the entire screen, leaving the borders as they are, using the logic I've shown in my answer. Get the coordinates of the monitor that the window is currently on, and change the size of the window to fill that entire monitor.

Comment: @Cody Gray, so to use your function i need first get handle of target window and then pass it as parameter?

Comment: @archer: No. Passing it to that function *exactly as written* will create a window. Since you want to customize the window for an *external* application, you don't want to do that. Instead, you need to get the handle to the window, get the coordinates of the monitor that the window is currently located on, and resize the window (using the `SetWindowPos` function, if you're in C++; no one knows which language you want to use) to fill the coordinates of that monitor.

Comment: It's very difficult to provide quality answers to a question that leaves us guessing at the details. What programming language do you want to use? What is this external application that you're trying to start? Why do you need to alter its border style and window position to cover the taskbar? If you intend it to be a shell replacement, it would be much easier to use it that way instead of `explorer.exe`. That's a simple Registry edit, and much more secure than trying to hide the taskbar.

Comment: @Cody Gray, i didn't added any details coz they are no matter. Its just a standard window of application (like notepad). I want to make loader that will increase working area by hiding title, borders and placing it over taskbar (like fullscreen).

Comment: @archer: Right-click on your taskbar, choose "Properties", and uncheck the box labeled "Keep the taskbar on top of other windows". No application required.

Comment: Before changing position added `SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);` Now works as i want. Thanks.

Comment: @archer: All that does is make the window visible. You didn't mention that the window was hidden before. Also, you should use [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898.aspx) now for compatibility with 64-bit architectures.

Comment: @Cody Gray, window wasn't hidden before. This line just "erases" other window styles as i understand.

Comment: @archer: Ah, I see. Yeah, it sets `WS_VISIBLE` as the window's *only* style. A great way to break applications that depend on having particular window styles. I am amazed every day at the number of questions where people want to tamper with the internals of other applications. I hope the resulting developments never get anywhere near my machine.

Comment: @Cody Gray, don't worry, i will not give you this app :) And thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

try to use next

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
this.TopMost = true;
```

in case of PInvoke try this code

```
public static IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = (IntPtr)(-1);
public const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,int x,int y,int cx,int cy, UInt32 uFlags);
```

And call this

```
 IntPtr handle = this.Handle // or Handle to another window
 SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right,
                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Comment: @Stecya This does not hide the taskbar which OP wanted.

Comment: created new project, added this code to constructor and it definetly HIDES taskbar

Comment: @Stecya, i need to change window style of external app window, not my own.

Comment: @Stecya Oops! It does hide the Taskbar. Apologies.

Comment: @archer - then you should use `WINAPI` to change `Windows style`. You can do this ethier in c++ or in c# via `PInvoke`